# Teradata SQL - Create temporary table

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Is it possible to create a temporary table in a select statement.

So say I would like to have the dataset with the values (1,2,3,4,5) in a column ACCOUNT_NO.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NO FROM (1,2,3,4,5)
WHERE ACCOUNT_NO NOT IN (SELECT ACCOUNT_NO FROM OTHER_TABLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a CTE?

```
WITH a as (
      SELECT a.*
      FROM ((SELECT 1 as ACCOUNT_NO) UNION ALL
            (SELECT 2 as ACCOUNT_NO) UNION ALL
            (SELECT 3 as ACCOUNT_NO) UNION ALL
            (SELECT 4 as ACCOUNT_NO) UNION ALL
            (SELECT 5 as ACCOUNT_NO)
           ) a
     )
SELECT a.ACCOUNT_NO 
FROM a
WHERE a.ACCOUNT_NO NOT IN (SELECT ot.ACCOUNT_NO FROM OTHER_TABLE ot)
```

Comment: I don't know what a CTE is

Comment: @klippy . . . It is the `a` which is introduced with `with`.

Comment: Common Table Expression, or CTE, is a temporary named result set (id est your temporary table) derived from a select statement, for instance, and wrapped with the "with $resulset as (...)" expression to be used for subsequent querying. Very useful and very fast in TD.